# Khan Academy to Canvas grouping assignments by dates

Tags: python, csv

I am a math teacher, trying to automate the process of exporting scores from a Khan Academy class CSV export, to read the dates and group the assignments by student by date.

| Students | Assignment | Due Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Student1 | Add | 1/1/21 |
| Student2 | Add | 1/1/2 |
| Student1 | Subtract | 1/1/21 |
| Student2 | Subtract | 1/1/21 |

I need to figure out how to group the assignments by student by due date, so that if they got credit for both assignments it would on that due date it would spit out Student 1 10 points for 1/1/21 assignments etc.

Mainly I need to group all of Student 1 assignments on a specific day together and calculate a score.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show your expected output for your example?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how Khan Academy data is formatted, but here's a rough prototype that might help:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

data = """Students,Assignment,Due Date
Student1,Add,1/1/21
Student2,Add,1/1/21
Student1,Subtract,1/1/21
Student2,Subtract,1/1/21""".strip().splitlines()

# Column headers
cols = data[0].split(",")
# Column mapper object.
col_map = {i:v for i, v in enumerate(cols)}


def as_datetime(date_string, date_format="%m/%d/%y"):
    """Return datetime object."""
    return dt.strptime(date_string, date_format)


# list object for all student data from csv.
khan_data = []
for row in data[1:]:
    # Temp dict to hold current student data.
    tmp = {}
    for idx, el in enumerate(row.split(",")):
        tmp[idx] = el
    data_dict = {col_map[k]:v for k, v in tmp.items()}
    # data_dict["Due Date"] = as_datetime(data_dict["Due Date"]) # Uncomment to format Due Date field.
    data_dict["Assignment Score"] = 0. # For holding student score for the assignment.
    data_dict["Assignment Possible"] = 0. # For recording total possible points on the assignment

    # Append data to khan academy list.
    khan_data.append(data_dict)

def filter_students(student_id, due_date, data_list = khan_data):
    """Return list of entries by student id and due date.
    """
    output = []
    for entry in data_list:
        if entry["Students"] == student_id and entry["Due Date"] == due_date:
            output.append(entry)
    return output

filter_students("Student1", "1/1/21", khan_data)
```

Output:

```
[{'Students': 'Student1',
  'Assignment': 'Add',
  'Due Date': '1/1/21',
  'Assignment Score': 0.0,
  'Assignment Possible': 0.0},
 {'Students': 'Student1',
  'Assignment': 'Subtract',
  'Due Date': '1/1/21',
  'Assignment Score': 0.0,
  'Assignment Possible': 0.0}]
```